# cordovaSocialSharing in ionic not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using the plugin cordovaSocialShare of NgCordova to make sharing on social networks in my application. The problem is that I don’t have actions returned, and when analyzing the ADB logs, it returns me the following error:

```
I / chromium (3635): [INFO: ISLAND (20306)] "TypeError: Can not call method 'canShareVia' of undefined
I / chromium (3635): Scope at $ scope.shareViaWhatsapp. (File: ///android_asset/www/js/app.js: 22: 31)
```

Look at the code:

HTML

```
<ion-option-button class="button-dark button-facebook" ng-click="shareAnywhere()">
        <i class="icon ion-social-facebook icon-facebook"></i>
</ion-option-button>
```

AngularJS

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
$scope.shareViaWhatsapp = function(message, image, link) {
    $cordovaSocialSharing.canShareVia("whatsapp", message, image, link).then(function(result) {
        $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaWhatsapp(message, image, link);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Cannot share on Whatsapp");
    });
}

$scope.shareAnywhere = function() {
    $cordovaSocialSharing.share("This is your message", "This is your subject", "www/imagefile.png", "http://blog.nraboy.com");
}});
```

Someone could help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, again, I decided the problem by myself ...

The result:

In command line:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-SocialSharing
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.share = function($title, $excerpt, $permalink) {
      $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();
      window.plugins.socialsharing.share($title, $excerpt, null, $permalink);
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-option-button class="button-positive button-share" ng-click="share('{{item.title}}', '{{item.excerpt}}', '{{item.permalink}}')">
        <i class="icon ion-android-share-alt"></i>
</ion-option-button>
```